# AttributeError: Can't get attribut *имя атрибута*

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, ооп

Не понимаю в чём заключается ошибка. Вот небольшой код, связанный с **ООП** (По типу создания базы данных):

```
class Employ:
    def __init__(self, name=None, age=0, pay=0, job=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pay = pay
        self.job = job
    def __str__(self):
        return ('%s\n%s ==> %s'%(self.name, self.job, self.pay))
    def LastName(self):
        return self.name.split()[-1]
    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        self.pay *= (1.0+(percent/100))

class Manager(Employ):
    def __init__(self, name, age, pay):
        Employ.__init__(self, name, age, pay, job='manager')
    def giveRaise(self, percent, bonus=0.1):
        Employ.giveRaise(self, percent + bonus)
```

Далее я заключаю тестовый код в инструкцию`__name__ == '__main__'` и импортирую модуль 'shelve':

```
    ...Employ.giveRaise(self, percent + bonus)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bob = Employ('Bob Smith', 42, 40000, 'dev')
    sue = Employ('Sue Jones', 45, 50000, 'hdw')
    tom = Employ('Tom Hanks', 54)
    pavel = Employ('Pavel Savelev', 20, 100000, 'fsdev')
    john = Manager('John Silverhand', 127, 60000)

    db = shelve.open('filename')
    db['bob'] = bob
    db['sue'] = sue
    db['tom'] = tom
    db['pavel'] = pavel
    db['john'] = john
    print(db['bob'])
    for i in db:
        print(i,'==>', db[i].name, db[i].pay)
    db.close()
```

После, когда я создаю нужный мне файл, я хочу вывести от туда некоторые значения путём:

```
import shelve


db = shelve.open('filename')
for key in db:
    print(key, '=>\n ', db[key])
    print('=='*8)
db.close()
```

*(новый файл)*

И в инструкции `db[key]` и в ней подобных я получаю ошибку **AttributeError: Can't get attribut Employ**

Однако если я импортирую классы **Employ** и **Manager** в новый модуль и в этом новом модуле напишу всё что было заключено в инструкции `__name__ == '__main__':`, то получать атрибуты из нового файла я смогу и не будет выходить ошибки **AttributeError**

Почему?

---

По итогу понял, что если я импортирую созданные мной классы `Employ` и `Manager`, то я получу данные, которые хочу вывести:

```
import shelve, Employ, Manager


db = shelve.open('filename')
for key in db:
    print(key, '=>\n ', db[key])
    print('=='*8)
db.close()
```

Но я не понимаю почему мне нужно импортировать мои классы, чтобы прочитать уже записанные файлы. (по идее же там должны храниться сформированный закодированный текст)

Comment: Лучше всё-таки показывать ошибку целиком. Я так понимаю проблема в том, что тот код, в котором вы читаете данные, не видит описания классов `Employ` и `Manager`. Нужно их или отдельным файлом сделать и импортировать туда тоже или ещё как-то так.

Comment: Никаких ошибок нет, всё проверил по отдельности.

Comment: Может ошибка находится не в этом участке кода?

Comment: @CrazyElf, @Nurlashka действительно, ошибка состоит в том, что я не импортировал в новый файл классы `Emloy` и `Manager`. После их объявления ошибки не возникает. И было бы неплохо объяснить, почему чтобы прочитать уже записанный файл мне нужно импортировать мои классы?